# Input validation : Remove value on backspace

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I am running into a query; I have multiple html input box on my webpage, even inside multiple table column where user can edit for business calculations.

1. Text box support positive as well as negative value
2. maxlength etc etc....

Problem is when user enter value in any text box; there are four ways he can clear the value if he intend to type another.

1. backspace or delete  - working fine
2. ctrl A + delete - working fine
3. ctrl A + backspace - working fine
4. select all text using mouse left click and dragging it to select
   text + backspace/delete

Fourth case is failing. Kindly help in 4th scenario.

**Code:**

```
<input type="text" id="tust"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById('tust').onblur = issueDes;    

$("input").on("keyup keydown",function (e) {
                if(this.value!='-')
                    while(isNaN(this.value))
                     this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'').split('').reverse().join('');

               });   
});
function issueDes() {
    $("#tust").val(this.value+"%");    
}
```

**Fiddle:** 
 [DEMO - MOST CLOSE I CAN RE-CREATE THIS SCENARIO](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhqesam/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect selction and keyCode. Hope this will work for you. Only selected value will remove.

```
arr = [08,127,46];
$(document).ready(function(){

document.getElementById('tust').onblur = issueDes;    

$("input").on("keyup keydown",function (e) {
     var checkCode = $.inArray( e.keyCode, arr );
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selectionRange = window.getSelection ().toString (); 
        if((selectionRange.length > 0) && (checkCode != -1)){
        var value = $("#tust").val();
            $("#tust").val(value.replace(selectionRange,""))
        }
    }

                if(this.value!='-')
                    while(isNaN(this.value))
                     this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'').split('').reverse().join('');



               });   
});
function issueDes() {
    var currVal = this.value;    
    if(currVal != "" && currVal.indexOf("%") == -1){
    $("#tust").val(this.value+"%");    
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/awug6h9a/6/) http://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/awug6h9a/6/

Comment: is there anything else you want me to do?